# SharePoint Archiving

Tags: sharepoint-server, content-type, retention, document-archiving

I am trying to set up an archiving system by using retention policies, to avoid facing the 5K limit in document libraries. My question is:
1. will a drop off library every face the 5K limit,
2. and most importantly do the short cuts left behind in the original location still count as part of the 5K limit?